# Javascript namespacing - is this particular method good practice?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I'm a javascript newbie, and I've come up with the following scheme for namespacing:

```
(function() {
    var ns = Company.namespace("Company.Site.Module");

    ns.MyClass = function() { .... };

    ns.MyClass.prototype.coolFunction = function() { ... };

})();
```

Company.namespace is a function registered by a script which simply creates the chain of objects up to Module.

Outside, in non-global scope:

```
var my = new Company.Site.Module.MyClass();
```

I'm particularly asking about the method by which I hide the variable `ns` from global scope - by a wrapping anonymous function executed immediately. I could just write `Company.Site.Module` everywhere, but it's not DRY and a little messy compared to storing the ns in a local variable.

**What say you? What pitfalls are there with this approach? Is there some other method that is considered more standard?**

Comment: @pimvdb Nifty idea, but it would look a bit weird with multiple extend for the class and the methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to scope classes like that, its only necessary if you have global variables outside of the class. I use this approach...

```
MyApp.MyClass = function() {
};

MyApp.MyClass.prototype = {
   foo: function() {
   }
};
```

Also note that I use a object literal for a cleaner prototype declaration

However if you need to scope global variables then you can do

```
(function() {
   var scopedGlobalVariable = "some value";

   MyApp.MyClass = function() {
   };
   MyApp.MyClass.prototype = function() {
       foo: function() {
       }
   };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks fine to me.

However, you can also do this slightly different, by returning the "class" from the self-executing function:

```
Company.Site.Module.MyClass = (function() {
    var MyClass = function() { ... };
    MyClass.prototype.foo = function() { ... };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

This strips at least all the `ns.` prefixes. The namespace function can still be utilized to create the objects, but outside of the self-executing function.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I have a few classes and a few free functions in every namespace - however, it seems like a good idea to combine yours with mine - creating the classes with TheClass as a local variable, stripping the ns inside the class declarations, but still having ns outside. Or do you think this is too much?

Comment: Sounds very reasonable to me!

Comment: Upvoting for now, but I think it's a custom on SO to wait for a day to allow others to answer before checking as accepted ;)